# What method to continuosly keep track the date last record for every day

Tags: php, mysql

I've a situation that user need to upload their product data every day. But if they did not upload any data more than two days there is should be a notification to warn them and more than 7 days for the last warning. I know to solve this date comparison but I dont know the method or function how to always keep track the last date record for every minute or date maybe. This is to make sure that there is no missing product in the database. Maybe we can call it automated alert.

Any expertise can advise the right method? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of CRON(Unix system). Which is a schedule based execution of script. You can set the CRON to run everyday and in the script you can check the earlier dates with respect to current date. So that everyday when the CRON runs on the scheduled time, it will execute the script for the new day.

Comment: I've read the cron before. But I did not very clear on how to implement it? it is simple code?

Comment: CRON ain't code. You need a script that is runable from the server (executable from others) and then write a set into the `crontab` which script should be running at what time

Comment: You are supposed to enable cron and set your script, a timing(schedule) to be run. Use this link to understand enabling and scheduling cron. Check the examples in the link to understand better.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: this cron can do multitasking job? Means that I can track the date as mentioned above and auto generate file at the same time?

Comment: The cron will just execute your php file at the time you set for it to run(schedule). It will just blindly execute your php script you pointed it to at the time you mentioned. Its upto your php script to track the date and generate the file.